# Combine add_compile_options and target_compile_options

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to combine `add_compile_options` with `target_compile_options`?

```
add_compile_options(-Wall)
add_library(A)
target_compile_options(A PRIVATE ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS})
```

Does this mean, target A get's build with `-Wall` and `${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}` ?

What I want to achive is to specify with `add_compile_options` common flags which should be set for all targets. And by using `target_compile_option` I want to extend the compile options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) appends (or prepends) compile options, not replaces them. So you already have what you want with the code in your question.